# Why am I still getting R10 error when trying to deploy an Express app

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I am trying to host an Express app on Heroku, but I keep getting the error: `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

When I tried to find a solution, I found a bunch of pages saying that heroku dynos use a dynamic port, and that it can be accessed with `process.env.PORT` as well as that you had to listen at the address `0.0.0.0`. I've done both of these things, and the program logs what I assume is the correct port on startup, but it still gives me the error. All of the people I've found who still had this error after fixing the port have either figured out how to fix it yet, or had some other issue that didn't apply here.

For now, I'm just trying to host a simple program, the code for which can be seen below.

```
const express = require("express")
let app = express()

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.send("testing")
})

const PORT = (process.env.PORT | 8080)

app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`listening on port *: ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: Is `process.env.PORT` set when you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is `(process.env.PORT | 8080)`.

`|` is a bitwise OR operation.

`||` is a logical OR operation.

You need to do `const PORT = (process.env.PORT || 8080);`

Here a simple test case:

```
console.log(1234 |  8080)  // 8146
console.log(1234 || 8080) // 1234
```